# Visual studio re-compilation - Project is not up to date. Input file 'filename' is modified after output file '?'

Tags: visual-studio

I see a lot of re-compilation in Visual studio.

14>Project 'Ivara.Client.Plugins.Hardware.PanasonicCamera' is not up to date. Input file 'C:\src\DotNet\Client\IvaraClient\obj\x64\Debug\IvaraClient.csproj.CopyComplete' is modified after output file '?'.

Wondering if the "output file '?'" indicates some sort of problem?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/4891

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this issue once and fixed it by:

Tools=>Options=>Environment=>Documents=>Check `Reload modified files unless there are unsaved changes`

[image]